# Add up property from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add up the ID property from an array of objects. The result displayed is 01395 - instead, it should be 27 *(as that's what 13 + 9 + 5 equals)*.

I believe the code is concatenating the ID properties rather the desired outcome of adding them.

```js
var collection = [{
  "Name": "Charlie",
  "ID": "13"
}, {
  "Name": "Emma",
  "ID": "9"
}, {
  "Name": "Bob",
  "ID": "5"
}];

total = 0, //set a variable that holds our total
  id = collection, //reference the element in the "JSON" aka object literal we want
  i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) { //loop through the array
  total += id[i].ID; //Do the math!
}
console.log(total); //display the result
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3r8vhfb2/

Comment: Use `parseInt()`, currently it concatenates as string.

Comment: What is a "JSON array"? `ID` is not an "element", it's a "property". "putting each element next to each other" is called concatenation. That's what `+` does with strings.

Comment: No, it would make it clearer to call it an "array".

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the behavior of `+` with strings vs. numbers is well-documented and covered in many questions here on SO, potentially making this question "not useful". For example, see the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Comment: @torazaburo I see. I don't see how this question is "not useful" though as it's a genuine mistake and rather than downvoting for a mistake, someone should correct the mistake in an answer so I can learn for next time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-using-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to `Number`

> [**`Unary plus (+)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), *The `unary plus operator` precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a `number`, if it isn't already.*

```js
var collection = [{
  "Name": "Charlie",
  "ID": "13"
}, {
  "Name": "Emma",
  "ID": "9"
}, {
  "Name": "Bob",
  "ID": "5"
}];

var total = 0,
  id = collection;
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  total += +id[i].ID;
  //OR total += Number(id[i].ID);
}
console.log(total);
```

**Or using** `Array#reduce` **:**

```js
var collection = [{
  "Name": "Charlie",
  "ID": "13"
}, {
  "Name": "Emma",
  "ID": "9"
}, {
  "Name": "Bob",
  "ID": "5"
}];

var total = collection.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return +(a.ID || a) + +(b.ID);
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I would like to thank you for posting this answer and showing me how to rectify the problem of concatenating the ID properties :)

Comment: @TheCodesee, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Which answer is better out of the two you posted, performance-wise?