# <windows.h> functions trigger POLINK error in Pelles C

Tags: c, winapi, pelles-c

I have a simple program (`program.c`) that I am compiling with Pelles C:

```
#include <windows.h>
void main() {
    char buffer[256];
    GetKeyboardState(buffer);
}
```

When I try to compile this program, [after enabling Microsoft Extensions](//stackoverflow.com/a/5462901/5223757), it fails:

> Building program.obj.
>   Building program.exe.
>   **POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol '__imp_GetKeyboardState'.**
>   **POLINK: fatal error: 1 unresolved external(s).**
>   *** Error code: 1 ***
>   Done.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Voting to re-open per [Rule proposal: Duplicate closure to roll-up questions are no longer allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/5223757). This is a C question (not a C++ question), and while the third answer is _relevant_, no answer to the duplicate says how to resolve the issue _in Pelles C_.

Comment: I don't see why this question should have been re-opened. The duplicate answers the question. If you have a follow-up question (*"How do I set linker options using Pelles C?"*), then that should be a different question. Closing again.

Comment: @IInspectable C and C++ are not the same programming language. The duplicate target provides answers for gcc, Xcode and MSVS. An expert might perceive a substantial overlap in the questions, the fact it _doesn't answer the question_ should factor into the decision, I feel. (This is a beginner-level question, after all – and last I checked, [the only search result for this error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22POLINK%3A+error%3A+Unresolved+external+symbol%22+windows.h&t=ftsa&ia=web) is a mirror of this question.)

Comment: *"C and C++ are not the same programming language."* - Correct. And if this were a programming language question, things would be different. But it isn't. It's a linker question, and C and C++ share the same build model (ignoring C++20 modules). The duplicate addresses the issue. If you need help setting up linker input for your IDE, that is a different question.

Comment: @IInspectable But many of the answers to that question are about C++-specific issues. _Now_, I could solve this issue with my eyes closed, and would not need to consult any reference material, but when I was new to C, I read through the entire duplicate target before asking this question and did not learn the answer from it.

Comment: @IInspectable Stack Overflow _does_ allow beginner questions, like [adding two numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496556/5223757), or [the existence of branch predictors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/5223757). It's only questions where the asker won't understand the answer that are banned.

Comment: Some people learn by memorising abstract models and observing how that's implemented at the concrete level. Other people learn by looking at concrete examples and generalising, and that's also a valid way to develop basic familiarity. I don't think we should be closing questions just because an expert wouldn't learn it that way: experts aren't the ones doing the learning! I especially don't think we should be closing questions as duplicates when the duplicate target _does not contain the answer_, and requires expertise to even understand that it _is_ a (supposedly) valid duplicate.

Comment: *"I especially don't think we should be closing questions as duplicates when the duplicate target **does not contain the answer**"* - Right, we should not be doing that. And that hasn't happened, either. As was [brought to your attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361784/windows-h-functions-trigger-polink-error-in-pelles-c#comment69927153_41361785) within 2 hours of asking the question. Would you rather have the [tag:c] tag look like the [tag:php] tag? I hope you understand that opinions like yours drive actual value off the platform. I'm done with kids *demanding* to get spoonfed.

Comment: This isn't a kid demanding to get spoonfed. Observe that it's a _self-answered Q&A_ that is the _only search result_ for «"POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol" <windows.h>»: this is a kid attempting to _share knowledge_ that otherwise requires developing expertise about arcana _ex nihilo_. If you object, [you can share your opinion in the meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/5223757), since nobody there seems to agree with you. At this point I hardly care any more: the fewer people developing for Windows, the better, in my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from POLINK: the linker. This suggests that the program needs to be linked to a library that it is not being linked to. The [documentation page for `GetKeyboardState`](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx) says that the required library in this case is `User32.lib`.

To link to the library, click "Project" -> "Project options...", then select the "Linker" tab. There will probably be libraries in the "Library and object files:" box; add the library (e.g. `User32.lib`, case insensitive) to this space-separated list.

Your program should now compile.

Comment: This has been asked so many times before. I do t this k we need yet another version of this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for marking as duplicate. I only asked this question because nothing was coming up in search results; now people who have my problem will be directed to the "original" question.

Comment: Somewhat hard to fathom. A search for your error message yields multiple results.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan None of them answered the question; at least none that I found. I worked the answer out myself (which wasn't too hard now that I know what a linker is) and posted this, after searching for duplicates (although probably not with the right keywords).

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1889329) addresses your specific issue, and provides an answer.