# summing float and integer with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some integer value to the float (maybe it's not float with this situation this is money format)
I have a money value like this: "4,918.05" and i want to add 30 to it.

```
        var inputs = $('.ig-control__cbx');
        var totalPrice = parseFloat($('.total-price-span').html());
        var add = 30;
        totalPrice = totalPrice +add
        $('.total-price-span').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
```

When i want to sum them i get 4 instead of total.
How can i fix it?

Comment: `parseFloat` does not recognize comma as a part of `number` so you recive just number before the first unrecognized character

Comment: This is a very basic fact with javascript. this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum

Comment: @Ankit And which of the answers fits on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can extend my comment to answer:

So `parseFloat` does not recognize comma as a part of `number` so you recive just number before the first unrecognized character. To solve this problem, you need to replace all commas in that string before parsing float. Something like this:

```
var inputs = $('.ig-control__cbx');

var strVal = $('.total-price-span').html().replace(/,/g,'');
var totalPrice = parseFloat(strVal);

var add = 30;
totalPrice = totalPrice +add
$('.total-price-span').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 4 from parseFloat("4,918.05"). To circumvent this you could use replace() to remove commas first.

```
var price = $('.total-price-span').html().replace(/,/g,'');
var totalPrice = parseFloat(price);
```