# How to add items returned from map function

Tags: reactjs

```
getTotalUserVotes = (userid) => {
  let posts = this.state.posts.slice();
  let current = posts.filter((item) => {
    return item.userid === userid;
  })
  console.log(current);
  const tot = current.map((item) => {
    return item.votes;
  })

  console.log("tot is " + tot) 
// this logs 50, 0 ,0 
//so each of the three posts that belong to that user have those amount
//of votes respectively.How can I add these? 
  return <div>votes: {tot}</div>;
}
```

When I have tried adding these using a for loop the strings concatenate so ill get 5000, I have searched how to stop that on stack overflow but none of the answers had little to any relation to my circumstance.
[somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum).

an example of the data in posts is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5qun.jpg)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/615ev58n/1/

Comment: `const tot = this.state.posts.reduce((total, item) => item.userid === userid? total + Number(item.votes): total, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reduce method instead of map to add each item's votes.

```
const tot = current.reduce((total, item) => total + Number(item.votes), 0);
```

However, you can actually filter, map and reduce all at once.

```
const getTotalUserVotes = (userid) => {

    const tot = this.state.posts.reduce((total, post) => {
        return post.userid === userid ? total + Number(post.votes) : total
    }, 0)

    return <div>votes: {tot}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Tried this implementation got TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This works. I looked at array reduce and I see that the optional parameter initial value is set to 0. Why do we need to do that? Why does it think the array is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `item.votes` to a Number (since it sounds like it's stored as a String) and then use your for loop or [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)  to sum the values:

```
const tot = current.map((item) => {
  return Number(item.votes);
})

tot = tot.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

Comment: still get 5000 with this implementation

Comment: That's odd: this is the same implementation as Callam's, except this casts to number in the `map` instead of the `reduce`.

const test = ['1', '2', '3'].map(i=>Number(i));
console.log(test.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)) // 6