# While loop and span tag in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an HTML coding exercise. The HTML file will let the users input a starting number, an ending number, and a step number. Then output all the even numbers between the starting number and the ending number by the step size after clicking a button. But so far nothing displays after the button is clicked. Also, I tried to insert text into the paragraph using span tags but that doesn't work.
Please help. Thank you.

```js
function validateItems(){
  var starting = document.forms["displayEvens"]["starting"].value;
  var ending = document.forms["displayEvens"]["ending"].value;
  var step = document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].value;
  var numbers = "";
  var adding = starting;
  if (starting == "" || isNaN(starting)){
    alert("Starting Number must be filled with a number");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["starting"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (ending == "" || isNaN(ending) || ending <= starting){
    alert("Ending Number must be filled with a number or must be greater than the starting number");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["ending"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (step == "" || isNaN(step) || step < 0){
    alert("Step Number must be filled with a number and must be positive");
    document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  while (adding < ending){
    adding = adding + step;
    if (adding % 2 == 0){
      numbers = String(adding) + " ";
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("first").innerText = starting;
  document.getElementById("second").innerText = second;
  document.getElementById("middle").innerText = step;
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerText = numbers;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="displayEvens.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Display Evens</h1>
    <form name="displayEvens" onsubmit="return validateItems();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starting">Starting Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="starting">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ending">Ending Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ending">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="step">Step</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="step">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Display Evens</button>
    </form>
    <p>Here are the even numbers between <span id="first"></span> and <span id="second"></span> by <span id="middle"></span>'s:</p><br />
    <p><span id="results"></span></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your snippets, there isn't an element with `id="numbers"` to match `getElementById("numbers")`. Should that reference `"results"` instead?

Comment: you're confusing strings for numbers so that `adding = adding + step` is a string concatenation and `while (adding < ending)` is a string comparison. And `"100" < "5" === true`.

Comment: You code may consider one even number which exceeds the limit. For example, `starting=2, ending= 6 and step=3`. First iteration, `2<6 and adding=5` 
Second iteration, `5<6 and adding=8` and it appends 8 to the string since it's an even number. But 8 exceeds 6.
Try this instead:
`adding = adding + step;
while (adding < ending){
   if (adding % 2 == 0){
      numbers = numbers+adding + " ";
    }
   adding = adding + step;
  }`

Comment: `isNaN` does not determine wether some value itself is *not a number*, it is only determining wether something is explicitely `NaN` (when cast to a number). so `isNaN("5") === false`, `isNaN([ "0xF"  ]) === false` even `isNaN({ foo: "lorem ipsum", toString(){ return "" }}) === false` because they all can be **cast to a number** that is **not** `NaN`

Comment: Also based on what Thomas mentioned:
`var starting =parseInt (document.forms["displayEvens"]["starting"].value);
  var ending = parseInt (document.forms["displayEvens"]["ending"].value);
  var step = parseInt (document.forms["displayEvens"]["step"].value);`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum

Comment: DRY! store `document.forms["displayEvens"]` in a local variable and use that variable instead of resolving the path over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I learned so much from this post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDITED (more complete answer)

You are reading in `value` from an `input` type element. Even though they are `type=number`, you still need to parse them as ints, or floats. By default they're strings when you read in `.value` from `input` elements. Right now you're just adding the `step` number (which is also as a string) to a string of the `adding` variable. If `starting/adding=1` and the `step=1`, then it's just concatenating the string, like this:

```
1
11
111
...and so on (the while loop will never end at this rate...)
```

When you're setting the variables and pulling from the DOM elements, just pass them through the `parseInt` function that's built into javascript.

Also, when I think you MEANT to concatenate, you weren't. (Append the even number to the `number` string that you're displaying)

`number += adding + ' ';`

Finally, make sure you're displaying the `numbers` element in the right id: `results`.

Here is a fully working example based on what work you did, with the code a little bit dryer and a couple of other nuances caught:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Display Evens</h1>
    <form name="displayEvens" onsubmit="return validateItems();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="starting">Starting Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="starting">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ending">Ending Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ending">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="step">Step</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="step">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Display Evens</button>
    </form>
    <p>Here are the even numbers between <span id="first"></span> and <span id="second"></span> by <span id="middle"></span>'s:</p><br />
    <p>
      <span id="results"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function validateItems(){
        var form = document.forms["displayEvens"];
        // parsing the numbers as ints
        var starting = parseInt(form["starting"].value);
        var ending = parseInt(form["ending"].value);
        var step = parseInt(form["step"].value);
        var numbers = "";
        var adding = starting;
        if (starting == "" || isNaN(starting)){
          alert("Starting Number must be filled with a number");
          form["starting"].focus();
        return false;
        }
        if ((ending == "" || isNaN(ending) || ending <= starting) &&
        (starting < 0 && ending !== 0)){ // An extra scenario that was problematic...
          alert("Ending Number must be filled with a number or must be greater than the starting number");
          form["ending"].focus();
          return false;
        }
        if (step == "" || isNaN(step) || step < 0){
          alert("Step Number must be filled with a number and must be positive");
          form["step"].focus();
          return false;
        }
        while (adding < ending){
          adding = adding + step;
          if (adding % 2 == 0 && adding !== ending){ // Exclude the ending number
            numbers += adding + " ";
          }
        }

        document.getElementById("first").innerText = starting;
        document.getElementById("second").innerText = ending;
        document.getElementById("middle").innerText = step;
        document.getElementById("results").innerText = numbers; // corrected id
        return false;
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @NancySchroepfer Glad to help. Honestly, most important, you should learn how to use `console.log()` and view those logs to help with debugging. Would you please mark my answer as the solution? Thank you!