# simple javascript addition, where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get it to add the two numbers inputted by the user, and print it inside of the p tag. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Enter in the values you want to add</h2>
    <form>
        <input id="num1" name="num1" type="number"> //value one
        </br>
        <input id="num2" name="num2" type="number"> //value two
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button> //Click to calculate
    </form>
    <p id="p">The answer will show here</p>
    <script>
        var p1=document.getElementById("p");
        var p=p1.innerHTML;
        var calc=document.getElementById("calculate");
        calc.addEventListener("click", answer); //When the button is clicked it calls the function answer()
        function answer() {
            var num1=document.getElementById("num1");
            var num2=document.getElementById("num2");
            var x=num1.innerHTML;
            var y=num2.innerHTML;
            p=x+y; //print the sum of the two values, inside of the p tag
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: p1.innerHTML = p;

Comment: `.innerHTML` returns a string and not the property itself, hence `p=x+y` won't "output" anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: `var x=num1.value` - you need the value of the input - you should also use `parseInt()` - good to read up on

Comment: @Xufox I think the fact that nothing at all gets output is as much of a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, will try to address them one by one:

- **The `<button>`** by default is `type="submit"` which when pressed refreshes the whole page, not the intended behaviour. To fix it just need to add `type="button"`, which makes it behabe like a button that by itself does nothing.
- **The result of `p=x+y`**, you are doing nothing with it. `p` is just a variable containing the result of the operation, but you need then to insert it inside the `<p>` tag for it to show up. Adding this at the end of your `answer()` function should fix it: `p1.innerHTML = p;`.
- **The `<input>` values**, those are stored in the `value` property instead of the `innerHTML`. So it should look like this `var x=num1.value;` and `var y=num2.value;`.
- **The "sum"**, in JavaScript the `+` operator can be used both to *add* numerical values and to *concatenate* strings, and the engine chooses what to do guessing by the type of the values you are using, in your case `strings`. Because even if you type `1` in the input, retrieving it later with `.values` will return it as a string. You have to cast it back to a number to get the desired result. Just doing this is enought `var x=Number(num1.value);` and `var y=Number(num2.value);`.

And that's all.

Here you have your code with the fixes applied.

```html
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Enter in the values you want to add</h2>
    <form>
        <input id="num1" name="num1" type="number"> //value one
        </br>
        <input id="num2" name="num2" type="number"> //value two
        <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button> //Click to calculate
    </form>
    <p id="p">The answer will show here</p>
    <script>
        var p1=document.getElementById("p");
        var p=p1.innerHTML;
        var calc=document.getElementById("calculate");
        calc.addEventListener("click", answer); //When the button is clicked it calls the function answer()
        function answer() {
            var num1=document.getElementById("num1");
            var num2=document.getElementById("num2");
            var x=Number(num1.value);
            var y=Number(num2.value);
            p=x+y; //print the sum of the two values, inside of the p tag
            p1.innerHTML = p;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

*Sorry for the lengthy answer but tried to attack each error by itself and it's explanation as clear and simple as I can do.*

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer, I kind of pieced together my rookie mistakes from everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

To decode what's going on in your JavaScript, please see my annotations to the code:

```
var p1=document.getElementById("p");  // Stores a reference to an element with id "p" to variable p1
var p=p1.innerHTML;  // Retrieves the HTML contents of said attribute and assigns it to variable p (not needed)
var calc=document.getElementById("calculate");  // Stores a reference to an element with id "calc" (your button) to variable calc
calc.addEventListener("click", answer);  // Attaches an event handler to the element referenced via variable calc
function answer()
  {
  var num1=document.getElementById("num1");  // Stores a reference to an element with id "num1" in variable num1
  var num2=document.getElementById("num2");  // Stores a reference to an element with id "num2" in variable num2
  var x=num1.innerHTML;  // Retrieves the HTML contents of the element referenced by num1 and stores it in variable x (error)
  var y=num2.innerHTML;  // Retrieves the HTML contents of the element referenced by num2 and stores it in variable y (error)
  p=x+y;  // Since both x and y are strings, they are concatenated and the result is stored in variable p (produces wrong result)
// Missing assignment of result to output element
  }
```

The problem: You don't have a statement that actually assigns the result to the paragraph marked with ID "p", instead you are modifying a variable.
Furthermore, since you are retrieving strings from the input fields, the addition is in reality a concatenation, producing a false result (`num1.value` and `num2.value` are needed to access the actual values). I'd also suggest converting things to an integer - `parseInt` does the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = p1.innerHTML
```

copies the contents of your paragraph into the variable p.

So your

```
p = x+y
```

merely assigns a new value to your variable p and doesn't change the innerHTML of your paragraph.

Try

```
p1.innerHTML = (x + y) + '';   // + '' converts the result of x + y to a string
```

You should also use '.value' instead of '.innerHTML' to get the contents of your inputs and then convert them to numbers with parseInt() before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few issues; you can't copy the innerHTML of a p and then assign it a value. You must convert the input values to integers in order to add them. With inputs you can ask for their "value" rather than innerHTML.

```
<html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Enter in the values you want to add</h2>
    <form>
        <input id="num1" name="num1" type="number"> //value one
        </br>
        <input id="num2" name="num2" type="number"> //value two
        <button id="calculate">Calculate</button> //Click to calculate
    </form>
    <p id="p">The answer will show here</p>
    <script>
        var p1=document.getElementById("p");
        var calc=document.getElementById("calculate");
        calc.addEventListener("click", answer); //When the button is clicked it calls the function answer()
        function answer(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var num1=document.getElementById("num1");
            var num2=document.getElementById("num2");
            var x=parseInt(num1.value, 10);
            var y=parseInt(num2.value, 10);
            p1.innerHTML = x+y; //print the sum of the two values, inside of the p tag
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```