# Addition operator isn't working in Javascript. If I do 20+10, it gives me 2010 instead of 30. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, operators, addition

I am practicing Javascript operators but addition is not working. What should I do to fix the problem?

This for a new website. I gave 10+20. but in output i get 1020 instead of 30.

```js
var x="10";
var y="20";
var z=x+y;
```

I expect the output of 10+20 to be 1020, but the actual output is 30.

Comment: You're adding *strings* not numbers. You've got the values in quotes for some reason, so they're not numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to concatanate String instead.
Using quote explicity tell to the intertreter yours variables are string.
Discards them and you  will get your addition.

Comment: thank you boss..it is working now..thank you so much