# TypeScript: number addition 0 + 1 returns 01

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a Shoppingcard.

```
private _card: Map<Product, number> = new Map<Product, number>();

...

addToCard(prod: Product, amount: number = 1): void {
    const a: number = this._card.get(prod) + amount; // The current amount + new Items
    console.log(this._card.get(prod) + ' + ' + amount);
    this._card.set(prod, a);
  }
```

Log:

```
card.service.ts:31 0 + 1
card.service.ts:31 01 + 1
card.service.ts:31 011 + 2
card.service.ts:31 0112 + 2
card.service.ts:31 01122 + 3
card.service.ts:31 011223 + 4
```

Obviously it should do a normal addition. I don't know why this happens, all vars are decleared as number.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `this._card.get(prod)` is almost certainly really a string

Comment: You are apparently calling the function with a `string` instead of a `number` at runtime.  Where are you calling the function?  If it's in TS code, there should be an error/warning there.  If it's just in JS, you should make your TS expect that the input should be `unknown` or `any` and do a type guard to check if it's `number` or not

Comment: can you try `typeof this._card.get(prod)`

Comment: @jcalz it appears to be a TS code (there are types) but I agree that *there should have been an error*. I suspect OP did something like `el.value as number` expecting the value to be transformed, instead it's just telling the compiler "it's number" when it really isn't. A common problem.

Comment: (method) Map<Product, number>.get(key: Product): number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: ` console.log(typeof(this._card.get(prod))); `
retruns: 
` 
0 + 1
card.service.ts:32 number
card.service.ts:31 01 + 1
card.service.ts:32 string
`

Intressting

Comment: @EKnot As I said, I suspect you've used something to the effect of `stringValue as number` expecting the value to be transformed to a number. It isn't - you've just *lied* to the compiler saying "trust me - it's actually a number". The type doesn't change when you do a type assertion, only what the type system *thinks* the type is. At runtime, you still have a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can quick cast the card value into a number and then add the amount

```js
addToCard(prod: Product, amount: number = 1): void {
    const a: number = +this._card.get(prod) + +amount; // The current amount + new Items
    console.log(this._card.get(prod) + ' + ' + amount);
    this._card.set(prod, a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a:number = parseInt(this._card.get(prod), 10) + parseInt(amount, 10);
```

You could try wrapping in parse int with strict base 10.

Would allow you to be sure that both are numbers. Another thing you could try is

```
 const a:number = this._card.get(prod) += amount;
```

I would say one of these values, possibly the prod variable is being encoded as a string for some reason which is resulting in concatenation instead of addition.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this._card.get(cord) returns string, you can simply change it to below

```
addToCard(prod: Product, amount: number = 1): void {
    const a: number = +this._card.get(prod) + amount; // The current amount + new Items
    console.log(this._card.get(prod) + ' + ' + amount);
    this._card.set(prod, a);
  }
```

Comment: The error is far more pervasive than this and should be fixed at the root. The problem is that *for some reason* TS thinks `this._card.get(prod)` is a `number`. It should be a `string`, so it *knows* to throw a compilation error when you don't do that. Or, better yet, it *should* return a number, so you don't have to run a conversion everywhere you use this.