# How i add two variables

Tags: javascript

how to add two variables, I'm doing it like this and they are concatenating

```
id('total-quotas').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
           id('vl_total').value = (id('total-quotas').value + id('valor6').value);
        });
```

Comment: convert values to integers ! with parseInt

Comment: @epascarello another very relevant dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum

Answer (score 1):

They are concatenating because they are strings.

If you expect those two values to be numeric, then cast them via parseInt.

```
parseInt(id('total-quotas').value, 10) + parseInt(id('valor6').value, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these strings? If they are strings they will contact, if they are integers passed as strings you might need to parse as an integer

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Thankyou man i get here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp