# Adding var's together

Tags: javascript, input, addition, microsoft-edge, var

I was making a calculator because I was bored and I ran into a problem, when I try to do "x + y" (while x = 4 and y = 2) I get 42 instead of 6, can someone please explain this? (I'm using Edge)

here's the JS:

```
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("myText2").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("myText3").value;
    var a = x + y;
    if (z == "+") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = a;
    }

    if (z == "-") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x - y;
    }

    if (z == "*") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x * y;
    }

    if (z == "/") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x / y;
    }

}
```

The HTML:

```
<p>Your Problem:<br/><br/>
  <input name="myText" id="myText1" type="text" size="7"> <input name="myText" id="myText3" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1"> <input name="myText" id="myText2" type="text" size="7"> = <span id="demo3"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="myFunction1()">Calculate</button>
</p>
```

And the page/result:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to add strings together. You need to use `parseInt` to get the number part of the string. More info on `parseInt` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
function myFunction1() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myText1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("myText2").value);
    var z = document.getElementById("myText3").value;
    var a = x + y;
    if (z == "+") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = a;
    }

    if (z == "-") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x - y;
    }

    if (z == "*") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x * y;
    }

    if (z == "/") {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = x / y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did it solve your question? If it did accept my answer by pressing the check mark so other people can see that your question has been answered.

Comment: It did, but I can't accept it for another 6 min because of how fast you answered