# How to increment a variable inside .map() in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react code where it fetches all assessment year and populates in drop down but while displaying I wanted to increment it by one

suppose Assessment year is 2020 I want to show in drop down as FY : 2020-2021

Below code populates in dropdown when I try to increment it appends 1 instead of adding 1

```
   <select 
      class="form-control"  
      name="selected_FY"
      value="selected_FY" >

     {
         this.state.assessmentyears.map((fin, key) =>{
         return (  
          <option key={key} value={fin.year}>FY: {fin.year}-{fin.year+1}</option> 
          )
          })
       }                                  
 </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: It seems that `fin.year` is `string` instead of `number`. You have to first convert it into a number, e.g. `Number(fin.year) + 1`.

Comment: @theblackgigant no its a for reactjs code but it has pointed the mistake I have done, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding '1' to the string value. You should Parse it before incrementing.

```
<select 
      class="form-control"  
      name="selected_FY"
      value="selected_FY" >

     {
         this.state.assessmentyears.map((fin, key) =>{
         return (  
          <option key={key} value={fin.year}>FY: {fin.year}-{Number(fin.year)+1}</option> 
          )
          })
       }                                  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code

```
<option key={key} value={fin.year}>FY: {fin.year}-{Number(fin.year)+1}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem point is auto-type conversion in JavaScript, if type of your value is `string`, then you try to `+1`, the one will be auto change to `string`, so the calculation will `20201`(if the value is string `2020`).

The solution very easy, you just need to change type of your `value`,  if you want to adding 1, you can through `Number()`, That will change type from string to number, like as `Number('2020') + 1` will be `2020`.