# JS setHours on date is not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to increment the hours in a date:

```
let timerExpireDate = new Date(countdownStartDate);
console.log(`original date is ${timerExpireDate}`);
console.log(`add on ${countdownHours} hours`);
timerExpireDate.setHours(timerExpireDate.getHours() + countdownHours);
console.log(`New date is ${timerExpireDate}`);
```

However it also seems to be incrementing the days by 6, here is the console log:

```
original date is Sun Jul 19 2020 16:36:39 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
add on 2 hours
New date is Sat Jul 25 2020 18:36:39 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try running your code again in about... 10 minutes or so. See what happens.

Comment: You should provide a runnable snippet, with all values, next time

Comment: What are the values and type of `countdownStartDate`, `countdownHours` and how do they get their values?

Comment: @Code definitely got it right.  countdownHours is a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that `countdownHours` is of type string instead of number, so `timerExpireDate.getHours() + countdownHours` is `'162'` (6 days later) instead of `18`.

The fix is to cast `countdownHours` to number first, like `countdownHours = +countdownHours`.

Comment: It is by *complete coincidence* that `162` is 6 days and 18 hours, making the hours *look* right but the day "mysteriously" changing.

Comment: Might benefit from adding a runnable snippet showing why or a code block showing how to fix it