# Perform addition on string items inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying the following addition -

```
arr = ["12","15"];
let sum = arr[0] + 5;
console.log(sum)
```

It returns me 125 instead of 17. ( because 12 is a string ) I tried to convert this array into an array of numbers by using var string = JSON.stringify(arr).replace (/"/g,''); and then performing the addition but string[0] returns ' [ ' , for the obvious reason.

Is there a direct way to perform this addition?

Comment: you could cast it to number using `Number()` constructor `let sum = Number(arr[0]) + 5;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
arr = ["12","15"];
let sum = parseInt(arr[0]) + 5;
console.log(sum)
```

When any side of the `+` operation is a string then `+` operator does string concatenation in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert an array of strings to an array of numbers, is with `.map(Number)`:

```js
let arr = ["12","15"].map(Number);

console.log(arr);
```