# I am Confused why is this happening? Number(i) + Number(1);

Tags: javascript

I am very confused between string and number addition as you can see in this code I can't add "i"
with "1" as a number like whenever I try to do "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += "
" + i + 1;" I get answer 11 BTW the value of "i" is 1. I have found a solution for this but the thing is that i is also a number and 1 of course is then why I have to follow some strange pattern. For more information read the code below:

```
      function myFunction() {
        var text = "";
        var i;

        Loop1:
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += "<br>" + i + 1;
        }
          }
```

I can't write it like this because the computer will concat it like strings. So the solution I found looks like this:

```js
          function myFunction() {
            var text = "";
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += "<br>" + Number(i+1);
            }
           }
```

```html
<body onLoad="myFunction()">

<span id="demo"><span>

</body>
```

This works just fine but I don't understand why since I am new in the coding world.

Comment: `text += "<br>" + (i + 1);` Use parentehsis, currently everything is converted to a string.

Comment: Order of operations, left to right `(string + 1) + 1`

Comment: I because of the context. Because you started as string, code is evaluated as string, so "+" is used as concatenator, not operator. Either you make your addition out of the assignment or your can add parenthesis around

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: While you're at it, why not `for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` so you don't have to do `i+1` inside your loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
"<br>" + i + 1
```

is evaluated as

```
("<br>" + i) + 1
```

because addition/concatenation is [left-to-right associative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

I.e. `"<br>" + i` is executed first and will perform string concatenation because `"<br>"` is a string. The result will therefore be a string. Then you are performing `<string value> + 1` which will perform string concatenation for the same reasons.

The [grouping operator `(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) can be used to change the order of evaluation:

```
"<br>" + (i + 1)
```

Now `i + 1` will be evaluated first because it has a higher precedence due to the grouping operator (the result will be the number `2`) and then `"<br>" + 2` will be evaluated.

---

Btw, there is no need to overwrite the element's content in every iteration of the loop. Just built up the string and update the content after the loop:

```
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   text += "<br>" + (i + 1);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, the order in which **i** is added would make it add to the string first which will turn it into a string

**"`<br>`" + i** + 1;

When you use Number() to wrap it around it will no longer be turned into a string because it is now wrapped in a function call.

So basically
`"string" + 2` would make transform it into a string, which then your addition would be to the string.

Your second solution is basically `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += "<br>" + (i+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Adding operation works from the left to the right.

For example: `'' + 1 + 2` will be `"12"` as 1 will be added to the empty string first and then 2 will be added to the string `"1"`.
first step - `"" + 1  =  "1"`, second step - `"1" + 2 = "12"`

But if you wrap `"" + (1 + 2)` in the brackets it will be prioritized as in math.
first step - `(1 + 2)  =  3`, second step - `3 + "" = "3"`

In your case `Number()` does it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can not add a number to a string is that it will just add the number on and not really add them together

Here is an example

```js
number1 = "1";
number2 = 2;

number = number1 + number2;

console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text += "<br>" + i + 1
```

if you look you will see that you are saying, "text" + 1 + 1. This is one of the oddities of JavaScript being a dynamic language. When the interpreter reaches that it is trying to understand what you are trying to do:

- does Aneeq want to have: `text<br/>11`?
- does Aneez want: `text<br/> 2`?

etc

so when you are on the second snippet you are being explicit saying:
Ok I want you to:

1. get the text
2. concat the "
   " string to the `text` string
3. Convert the index, i, as a number and add the two number to together
4. Finally, add the sum to the previous string