# How can I add value to my args in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0]+1)
.then(messages => message.channel.send(`${emojiyes} Deleted **${messages.size}** messages!`) | console.log(`Deleted ${messages.size} messages!`))
```

This causes deleting for example 21 messages, not 2 (_clear 2 deletes 21 messages, not 3). Can someone help me?

Comment: `args[0]` is a string, you need to turn it into a number. Try `parseInt(args[0])` or `Number(args[0])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: Thank you so much for help! It worked!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args[0]` is a string and when combing that with one you are getting `"2"+1` which results in `21`. If you convert the string to a number first, it will calculate correctly. By using the `parseInt()` function we can convert the string into a number.

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0])+1)
.then(messages => message.channel.send(`${emojiyes} Deleted **${messages.size}** messages!`) | console.log(`Deleted ${messages.size} messages!`))
```

Comment: No problem! If my answer was correct you could vote for it by hitting the up arrow and mark it as the answer by hitting the checkmark.

Comment: I can't vote up, because I don't have 15 reputation points, sorry :(

Comment: That's fine! you should still be able to hit the checkmark (✓) to mark it as the answer!