# How to add values ​within the firebase database - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

Well, I have a little problem. I am developing a bot, and when the user executes a daily command, he earns "money" that is added to the database. But when he adds, he ends up looking like this:

**Expectation:** `610 + 491 = 1101`

**Reality:** `610 + 491 = 610491`

My code:

```
database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`).once('value').then(async function(db){

        let dbref = database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`);
//

            const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(process.env.COLOR)
            .setAuthor(` - Recompensa diária`)
            .setDescription(`Você coletou sua recompensa diária!
            
             Dinheiro Coletado: **\`R$${amount},00\`**`)
            .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send(embed1)

            dbref.update({
                money: db.val().money+amount,
                daily: Date.now()
            })

        }
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When summing two variables in JavaScript,
two behavior can be expected :

- summing numbers : the result is the sum of numbers
- summing string : the result is the concatenation of the strings.

Here one of your value, presumably `db.val().money`, is a string, therefore the result is the concatenation of the `db.val().money` and `amount`.

If you want the real sum, make sure to convert your variables to number with the `Number()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

because you adding strings, please convert is to integers first