# Data Saved as Strings, But need Ints

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I am retrieving data from a table.  The data is numbers, but it was saved as TINYTEXT in the mySql database. I can retrieve it and access it just fine, but I'm running into trouble because I need to add numbers.

So while I want 4 + 5 + 3 = 12.... instead I get the result of "453".

This is my calculation on the retrieved data:

```
let consultingScore = 0;
let consultingScoreDiv = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   let tempConScore = result[i].formValue01 + 
   result[i].formValue02 + result[i].formValue03;

   consultingScore = consultingScore + tempConScore;

   this.setState({ surveyScoreConsulting: consultingScore }); <--- (This should be 12, but is instead "453"
                }
```

I have tried to use parseInt() like below, but when I do, then the value then becomes NaN.  Am I not using parseInt correctly? It seems it should be easier than this to convert sting numbers to integers so I can perform calculations with them.

```
let consultingScore = 0;
let consultingScoreDiv = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
   let tempConScore = parseInt(result[i].formValue01) + 
   parseInt(result[i].formValue02) + parseInt(result[i].formValue03);

   consultingScore = consultingScore + tempConScore;

   this.setState({ surveyScoreConsulting: consultingScore }); <--- (This should be 12, but is instead "453"
                }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: Actually yes that fixed it.  Thanks!  I've never seen the solution of adding the +as a prefix to the variable before.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked, it's weird for me too first time I hear about this

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse with base 10, like this `parseInt(yourValue, 10)`

Comment: I just tried that, and it also gives me NaN.

Comment: are you sure about the values that you are parsing?

Comment: In the article the guy commented to me above, it suggested just added + as a prefix to the variables.  I did that and now it works as expected.  I had never heard of that before.