# JS: += is returning a weird result

Tags: javascript

I asked this question previously and it got redirected (and treated as answered) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum) - "Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum".

But it did not help me solve it, I did try parseInt, Number(), and putting + in front of my number.

So here is my question again, but before I think I need to **specify that I am using +=**, not just +.

---

I used this function to add 5 to a number in a p element:

```
function add5() {lifeTotal.textContent += 5;}
```

I have a similar function that subtracts 5 to that same number:

```
function minus5() {lifeTotal.textContent -= 5;}
```

Now my problem is that while the subtracting function works as expected, **the adding one just puts 5 at the right side of the number**. So if the number was 10, it would return 105, as if both numbers were actually strings and not numbers... **while the subtracting function works normally** and treats numbers as numbers...

It turns me crazy. I just learnt this += thing and I really don't think I used it wrong...

So my solution is to instead use ++ five times, like so:

```
function add5() {lifeTotal.textContent ++; lifeTotal.textContent ++; lifeTotal.textContent ++; lifeTotal.textContent ++; lifeTotal.textContent ++;}
```

It works, but it seems to me this is not the shortest way to write this.

The app I am writing is adding or subtracting by calling the corresponding function with an onclick="function()" in html button tags.

What is happening? What is the shortest way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `lifeTotal.textContent = +lifeTotal.textContent + 5` work?

Comment: wahou! Thanks, it works! 
I just don't understand why JS is behaving like this when the use of -= is so much more straightforward. Anyway, I learnt something new! 
I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is happening and why I need to use an = with a + in front of my Var. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got an explanation here from the original question, thanks to @PeterB : 

+ exists on string values and then it mean concatenation, so that is what happens. - is not defined on strings, but it is on numbers, so the string is converted to a number and then the numeric subtraction is applied. The end result is placed in the textContent property of what looks to be a DOM element, which can only store strings, so the numeric result of the subtraction is then stored again as a string value. – 
Peter B

Comment: I assume that the + in front of my Var lifeTotal is converting the DOM content targeted by the .textContent to a number, which let JS see 2 numbers instead of a string and the number 5.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aerial301 for this answer:

```
lifeTotal.textContent = +lifeTotal.textContent + 5
```

It works. I assume that the `+` in front of my Var `lifeTotal` is converting the DOM content targeted by the `.textContent` to a number, which let JS see 2 numbers instead of a string and the number 5.

Comment: This will work.  You might consider trying to store a number in `lifeTotal.textContent` in the first place -- currently a string is stored.  I would translate to a number immediately when first stored -- and then use it as a number from that point on.