# How do I make this function a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I wanted to accept user input and add a number to it ,but instead of outputting `12+12 =  24` it's outputting `12+ 12 = 1212`.

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function(){
  var myAge = document.getElementById("mytext").value + 12;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = myAge;
}
```

I tried doing:
 `myName = Number(myName)`
but it didn't work

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting; duplicate questions aren't permitted here in the interest of content quality. Duplicate of [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: I saw that post and it didn't help. that is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case use a function parseInt()
example:

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function(){
  var myAge = parseInt(document.getElementById("mytext").value) + 12;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = myAge;
}
```