# how do i sum up a value from an array depending on the date and id

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the following array instance

```
this.array=[{id:"121",score:"5",createdOn:"2022-05-17T19:52:23.6846702+00:00"}
            {id:"121",score:"8",createdOn:"2022-05-19T13:00:00.6846702+00:00"}
            {id:"122",score:"7",createdOn:"2022-04-11T08:00:00.6846702+00:00"}
            {id:"121",score:"1",createdOn:"2022-03-12T12:00:00.6846702+00:00"}

]
```

how do i some the values with a matching id and month.
for example my ouput should be

```
newArray=[{id:"121",score:13,month:"May"}
          {id:"122",score:7,month:"April"}
          {id:"121",score:1,month:"March"}


]
```

i tried something like this

```
this.array.forEach(item => {
            var obj = {}
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
                obj["id"] = obj[item.id] + parseFloat(item.score);
            }
            else {
                obj["id"] = parseFloat(item.score);
            }
            this.newArray.push(obj);
        });
```

But it didnt work and i dont know how to check the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fairly standard 'group by' using a compound key of `id_month`.

The example uses [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the array, [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to retrieve the month name from the ISO date string and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the compound key.

The `score` should be converted to a number before adding to avoid [accidental concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum), here using the [unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator.

Finally we take just the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the grouped object as the result.

```js
const array = [{ id: "121", score: "5", createdOn: "2022-05-17T19:52:23.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "121", score: "8", createdOn: "2022-05-19T13:00:00.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "122", score: "7", createdOn: "2022-04-11T08:00:00.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "121", score: "1", createdOn: "2022-03-12T12:00:00.6846702+00:00" },];

const result = Object.values(
  array.reduce((a, { id, createdOn, score, ...rest }) => {
    const month = new Date(createdOn).toLocaleDateString('en', { month: 'long' });

    a[`${id}_${month}`] ??= { id, month, score: 0, ...rest };
    a[`${id}_${month}`].score += +score;
    
    return a;
  }, {})
)

console.log(result)
```

The exact same logic can be used in a standard [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of within a `reduce()` call if you prefer.

```js
const array = [{ id: "121", score: "5", createdOn: "2022-05-17T19:52:23.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "121", score: "8", createdOn: "2022-05-19T13:00:00.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "122", score: "7", createdOn: "2022-04-11T08:00:00.6846702+00:00" }, { id: "121", score: "1", createdOn: "2022-03-12T12:00:00.6846702+00:00" },];

const grouped = {}

for (const { id, createdOn, score, ...rest } of array) {
  const month = new Date(createdOn).toLocaleDateString('en', { month: 'long' });

  grouped[`${id}_${month}`] ??= { id, month, score: 0, ...rest }
  grouped[`${id}_${month}`].score += +score;
}

const result = Object.values(grouped);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a temporary object to hold the updated information.
2. Because you need to separate out the objects that have the same ids but that were created on different months you can use a key `id-month` on the temporary object to identify them.
3. Loop over the array of objects [getting the month name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#using_options), and create the key. (I've used `Intl.DateTimeFormat` here because you can pass in a language string to get a different result from the function - try `'es-ES'` for example.)
4. If the property with that key [doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) on the temporary object add a default object to the temporary object with a default object value, and then increase its `score` (making sure you coerce it to a number first).
5. Finally get the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which will return an array of all those values in the temporary object.

```js
const arr=[{id:"121",score:"5",createdOn:"2022-05-17T19:52:23.6846702+00:00"},{id:"121",score:"8",createdOn:"2022-05-19T13:00:00.6846702+00:00"},{id:"122",score:"7",createdOn:"2022-04-11T08:00:00.6846702+00:00"},{id:"121",score:"1",createdOn:"2022-03-12T12:00:00.6846702+00:00"}];

const temp = {};
const language = 'en-GB';

function getMonth(createdOn, language) {
  const date = new Date(createdOn);
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(language, { month: 'long' }).format(date);
}

for (const obj of arr)  {

  const { id, score, createdOn } = obj;

  const month = getMonth(createdOn, language);
  const key = `${id}-${month}`;

  temp[key] ??= { id, score: 0, month };
  temp[key].score += Number(score);

}

console.log(Object.values(temp));
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [for/of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement)