# Why is addition in TypeScript weird?

Tags: typescript

I don't know why the addition using parameter in TypeScript is weird.

```js
const getDir = (lastIndex: number) => {
// my other code
console.log(lastIndex + 10) // result is 1010
}

getDir(10);
```

The result is showing **1010** instead **20**.

Anyone have an idea what I do wrong?

Comment: That's happening at runtime, in _JavaScript_. Evidently your type is not an accurate reflection of the real input.

Comment: Main problem: [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14496531) While your problem is that you are *not* calling `getDir(10);` [You can see that exact code is working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygEQJYCcYF4YAoA2AhtAJJgAmCAHgFwxgCuAtgEYLoCU2AfDAN4AoAPRCYTAJ4wQUABbsYoSgNCQQ+BADp8IOAWJQylKjADUMAIwAGLiJjoEEBvlioIFy1YEBfAQMQoMXCsOAG4gA). Most likely you are calling something that amounts to `getDir(someValue as number);`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for advice. when I changed the type number to any and do parseInt(lastIndex) first, the result is 20 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a `type` in TypeScript *does not handle the conversion*. You have to do that yourself.

In your example, the argument being passed to your `getDir` function is a string and not a number.

The exact code you have posted in your answer does what you want it to (produces `20`). You can check that out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygEQJYCcYF4YAoA2AhtAJJgAmCAHgFwxgCuAtgEYLoCU2AfDAN4AoAPRCYTAJ4wQUABbsYoSgNCQQ%20BADp8IOAWJQylKjADUMAIwAGLiJjoEEBvlioIFy1YEBfAQMQoMXCsOAG4gA)

If you don't handle the conversion, `string + string` in javascript will be a concatenation and not an addition.

There are multiple ways to convert strings to number in JavaScript. The most simple way is to throw a `+` in front of your number. (`+'10' + 10`)

Example:

```js
console.log('Should be 20: ', 10 + 10)
console.log('Should be 1010: ', '10' + 10)
console.log('Should be 20: ', +'10' + 10)
```

Comment: Hahaha fool of me, I was relying too much in the power of types on typescript