# How to change the left position of div instance with arrow key using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, please bear with me.
When the right arrow key is pressed I would like to change the div 100 pixels to the right. I use my own class to create a square and then try to change this instance position.

```
class Square {
  constructor(length) {
    this.width = length;
    this.height = length;

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.style.position = "absolute"; // to be able to move it
    this.div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.div.style.width = length + "px";
    this.div.style.height = length + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);

    this.xPos = 50;
    this.div.style.left = this.xPos + "px";

  }
}

var square2 = new Square(10);

window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
    }

    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        alert("ArrowDown");
        // Do something for "down arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowUp":
        // Do something for "up arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
        alert("ArrowLeft");
        // Do something for "left arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
        alert("ArrowRight");
        square2.div.style.left += 100 + "px"; // this code does nothing?
        
        break;

      default:
        return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
    }

    // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  true
);
```

The code `square2.div.style.left += 100 + "px";` does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't do nothing, it just doesn't do what you intend.

`square2.div.style.left` is set to `50px` which you are then concatenating with `100 + 'px'` which results in `50px100px`.

The longhand solution is to parse out the number every time by stripping off the `px`, converting the string to a number ([to avoid concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)) and then adding to it.

```
square2.div.style.left = +square2.div.style.left.replace('px', '') + 100 + "px";
```

But this is cumbersome at best. The simpler solution is to declare a `left` property and increment it in your listener.

```
class Square {
  constructor(length) {
    
    ...
    
    this.xPos = 50;
    this.div.style.left = this.xPos + "px";
    
    this.left = this.xPos; //<-- declare new left prop set to initial value
  }
}

window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (event) {
  
  ...
  
  case "ArrowRight":
        square2.left += 100; // increment left prop 
        square2.div.style.left = square2.left + "px";
```

```js
class Square {
  constructor(length) {
    this.width = length;
    this.height = length;

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.style.position = "absolute"; // to be able to move it
    this.div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.div.style.width = length + "px";
    this.div.style.height = length + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);

    this.xPos = 50;
    this.div.style.left = this.xPos + "px";
    
    this.left = this.xPos;

  }
}

var square2 = new Square(10);

window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
    }

    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        alert("ArrowDown");
        // Do something for "down arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowUp":
        // Do something for "up arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
        // Do something for "left arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
        square2.left += 100;
        square2.div.style.left = square2.left + "px"; // this code does nothing?
        
        break;

      default:
        return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
    }

    // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way to handle visual state changes in html using vanilla js is to actually use vanilla CSS.  It's less code.  It's cleaner.  It's easier to support for other devs down the line.

1. Add a data attribute to the html element
2. Add a css class to the attribute
3. Add eventlistener for the arrow down key to exectute.
4. You can do this for any element...input, div etc...

```js
input_element.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
        event.target.dataset.shift = 'right'
    }
    if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
        event.target.dataset.shift = 'default'
    }
})
```

```css
.shift[data-shift='right'] {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_element" class="shift" data-shift="default" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
class Square {
  constructor(length) {
    this.width = length;
    this.height = length;

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.style.position = "absolute"; // to be able to move it
    this.div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.div.style.width = length + "px";
    this.div.style.height = length + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);

    this.xPos = 50;
    this.div.style.left = this.xPos + "px";

  }
}

var square2 = new Square(10);

window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (event) {
   // if (event.defaultPrevented) {
   //   return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
   // }
    
    console.log(event.key)

    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        alert("ArrowDown");
        // Do something for "down arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowUp":
        // Do something for "up arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowLeft":
        alert("ArrowLeft");
        // Do something for "left arrow" key press.
        break;

      case "ArrowRight":
        alert("ArrowRight");
        square2.div.style.marginLeft += 100 + "px"; // this code does nothing?
        
        break;

      default:
        return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
    }

    // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  true
);
```