# Weird behavior when passing a random number to html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have the following HTML file where I want a number level within 50% of a given target (the "Level" field) to be input into the "Attribute" field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <input type = "number" name = "playerLevel" onchange = "populateAttributes()" id = "playerLevel">
        <label for = "playerLevel">Level</label>
    </body>

    <br>

    <tr>
        <td><input type = "number" id = "attributeScore"></td>
        <label for = "attribute">Attribute</label>
    </tr>

    <script src = "script.js"></script>
</html>
```

And I have the following Javascript code to generate random numbers

```
function generateRandomLevel(targetLevel)
{
    const target = targetLevel; // The target around which the random levels are generated
    const range = 0.5;  // 0.5 => 50% deviation from target and so on
    const upperLevelLimit = Math.round(target + target * range);    // Target + 50% deviation
    const lowerLevelLimit = Math.round(target - target * range);    // Target - 50% deviation
    let x = parseInt(Math.random() * (upperLevelLimit - lowerLevelLimit) + lowerLevelLimit);    // Generate Level within 50% of target
    return x;
}

function populateAttributes()
{
    let y = generateRandomLevel(document.getElementById("playerLevel").value);  // Passes the value of "playerLevel" to the random nunber generator
    document.getElementById("attributeScore").value = y;    // Set the value inside "playerLevel" to the random number generated
}
```

However, when I update the "Level" field, I get numbers totally out of range of the target like 72 incase of entering 10 into the "Level" field.

Does anyone know why this happens?

When I run the random number generator as a standalone, it works just fine, i.e

```
function generateRandomLevel(playerLevel)
{
    const target = playerLevel;
    const range = 0.5;
    const upperLevelLimit = Math.round(target + target * range);
    const lowerLevelLimit = Math.round(target - target * range);
    let x = parseInt(Math.random() * (upperLevelLimit - lowerLevelLimit) + lowerLevelLimit);
    return x;
}

console.log(generateRandomLevel(10));
```

Comment: [Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496531/adding-two-numbers-concatenates-them-instead-of-calculating-the-sum)

Comment: As has been pointed out, this is not HTML specific, it's that element in HTML are strings, and in your standalone example it will do the same if you pass a string, -> `generateRandomLevel("10")`  To make your function handle this case, just do -> `const target = Number(playerLevel);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this `document.getElementById("playerLevel").valueAsNumber` to use valueAsNumber

```js
function generateRandomLevel(targetLevel)
{
    const target = targetLevel; // The target around which the random levels are generated
    const range = 0.5;  // 0.5 => 50% deviation from target and so on
    const upperLevelLimit = Math.round(target + target * range);    // Target + 50% deviation
    const lowerLevelLimit = Math.round(target - target * range);    // Target - 50% deviation
    let x = parseInt(Math.random() * (upperLevelLimit - lowerLevelLimit) + lowerLevelLimit);    // Generate Level within 50% of target
    return x;
}

function populateAttributes()
{
    let y = generateRandomLevel(document.getElementById("playerLevel").valueAsNumber);  // Passes the value of "playerLevel" to the random nunber generator
    document.getElementById("attributeScore").value = y;    // Set the value inside "playerLevel" to the random number generated
}
```

because `value` is treated as a string

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `value` property from an `<input>` will always be  a string. You need to parse the value to a number with `parseInt(targetLevel, 10);`

See the below that does this, but also logs out the type and value.

This is a problem because doing math on strings actually does work in JavaScript and you can get weird results like this.  For example `5 + 5` will produce `10` as you'd expect, but `"5" + "5"` will produce `"55"` and `"55" * 0.5` will produce `52.3` - this is where your strangeness is coming from

```
Math.round("5" + "5" * 0.5) //53
Math.round(5 + 5 * 0.5) //8
```

```js
function generateRandomLevel(targetLevel) {
  console.log(typeof targetLevel, targetLevel);
  const target = parseInt(targetLevel, 10); // The target around which the random levels are generated
  console.log(typeof target, target);
  const range = 0.5;  // 0.5 => 50% deviation from target and so on
  const upperLevelLimit = Math.round(target + target * range);    // Target + 50% deviation
  const lowerLevelLimit = Math.round(target - target * range);    // Target - 50% deviation
  let x = parseInt(Math.random() * (upperLevelLimit - lowerLevelLimit) + lowerLevelLimit);    // Generate Level within 50% of target
  return x;
}

function populateAttributes() {
  let y = generateRandomLevel(document.getElementById("playerLevel").value);  // Passes the value of "playerLevel" to the random nunber generator
  document.getElementById("attributeScore").value = y;    // Set the value inside "playerLevel" to the random number generated
}
```

```html
<input type = "number" name = "playerLevel" onchange = "populateAttributes()" id = "playerLevel">
<label for = "playerLevel">Level</label>

<br/><br/>

<input type = "number" id = "attributeScore">
<label for = "attribute">Attribute</label>
```